# None response from a function http in JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, function

I'm coding a request HTTP in a JS function, but it not work (none message in console, none response, none data). Though, is not my first time in request HTTP, but I not find the error i n my code.
Can you enlighten me ?
Here is my code :

```
function dmd_art(){
  var httpRequest = getHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4){
      document.getElementById('annimation_loader').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('aff_pub').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
    }  
  }
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'includes/article.php', true)
}
```

`getHttpRequest()` is a function to adapted `XMLHttpRequest` to all web browsers

Comment: You are missing httpRequest.send() at the end according to https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function dmd_art(){
  var httpRequest = getHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4){
      document.getElementById('annimation_loader').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('aff_pub').innerHTML = httpRequest.responseText;
    }  
  }
  httpRequest.open('GET', 'includes/article.php', true)
  httpRequest.send(/* If there're some data send here */); // Add this
}
```

Yeah, missing something right?
If you don't send the request, that does nothing.

Comment: I added it and it works.  I did not know that it was necessary to put a send to a GET request, I thought that the send was only used to send data via a POST method for example.  I was wrong, thank you very much!